# Power BI count distinct IDs with a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a data that looks like this:

| Date | TicketId | Step | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 13:00:00 | 123456 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:00:00 | 123456 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:00:05 | 123456 | 8 | Error |
| 01.01.2020 13:05:00 | 123456 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:05:00 | 123456 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:05:05 | 123456 | 8 | Error |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 123456 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 123456 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:05 | 123456 | 8 | Error |
| 01.01.2020 13:15:00 | 123456 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:15:00 | 123456 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:05:00 | 654321 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:05:00 | 654321 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:05:05 | 654321 | 8 | Error |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 654321 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 654321 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:05 | 654321 | 8 | Error |
| 01.01.2020 13:15:00 | 654321 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:15:00 | 654321 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 098765 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 098765 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:05 | 098765 | 8 | Error |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 098765 | 2 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:00 | 098765 | 4 | Successfull |
| 01.01.2020 13:10:05 | 098765 | 8 | Error |

From that data I have a matrix that calculates the distinct quantity of TicketIDs that have a step = 8 (Result = 'Error').

**I need a DAX measure to calculate distinct number of TicketIDs if the TicketID have the Result = 'Successfull' as a last, before he had a Result = 'Error'. Note that next I will need to drillthrogh through the mesaure up to found TicketId.**

Example of the desired output:

| Date | Count_distinct_TickedId_with_Errors | Count_distinct_TickedId_with_Successfull_and_Errors_before |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 3 | 2 |

It's a 123456 and 654321 TickedIds.

Current DAX measure to calculate distinct TickedIds with errors looks like this:

1. LogDistcount_ = DISTINCTCOUNT(Logging[TicketId])
2. Errors_dist = CALCULATE(Logging[LogDistcount_], Logging[Step] = 8)

**And also, if it's not hard, the measure to calculate the TickedId, which is still have an Error result as at last.**

| Date | Count_distinct_TickedId_with_Errors | Count_distinct_TickedId_with_Successfull_and_Errors_before | Count_distinct_TickedId_with_Errors_still |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

It's a 098765.

**Many thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a date column in Power Query. In Power Query, select your current "Date" column (which apparently does not contain dates!), go to "Add Column" and click "Date" -> "Date Only". This adds a new column called `Date.1`. Close and apply to get your date column into your data model.
2. Add your measures:

```
Distinct_IDs_With_Errors = 
CALCULATE ( 
    COUNTROWS ( DISTINCT ( 'Table'[TicketId] ) ) , 
    'Table'[Step] = 8, 
    'Table'[Result] = "Error"
)
```

```
Distinct_Successful_After_Error = 
VAR _hasError = CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( 'Table'[TicketId] ) , 'Table'[Result] = "Error" )

VAR _table = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        FILTER ( 
            'Table' , 
            'Table'[TicketId] IN _hasError 
        ) ,
        'Table'[TicketId] ,
        "Max" , MAX ( [Date] )
    ),
    "Success_Last",
    VAR _max = [Max]
    VAR _last = 
        CALCULATE ( 
            SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Result] ) , 
            'Table'[Date] = _max
        )
    RETURN
        IF ( _last = "Successfull" , 1 )
)
RETURN
SUMX ( _table , [Success_Last] )
```

```
Distinct_Error_is_last = 
VAR _table =  
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Table' ,
            'Table'[TicketId] ,
            "Max" , MAX ( 'Table'[Date] )
            ),
        "Last_Error" , 
        VAR _max = [Max] 
        VAR _last = 
            CALCULATE ( 
                SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Result] ) ,
                'Table'[Date] = _max
            )
        RETURN
            IF ( _last = "Error" , 1 )
    )
RETURN SUMX ( _table , [Last_Error] )
```

Used in a visualization:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Jusr tried. It's strange how is it possible, but I have some kind of strange, different numbers. For example, Distinct_IDs_With_Errors calculates correctly, 25 rows and IDs. Distinct_Successful_After_Error calculates 15, which is not supposed, waited something like 24, and no IDs in matrix. Distinct_Error_is_last calculates null, blank. I've added a new column where only dates, no time at all.